# internal error; cannot instantiate () at <anonymous <any>> to ()

Tags: java

I'm getting the following error with some Java code I've written:

`internal error; cannot instantiate () at <anonymous <any>> to ()`

What I've done is created an interface similar to `java.lang.Comparable`, which is defined as follows:

```
public interface Comparable<T>
{
    public int compareTo(T o);
}
```

My interface is:

```
public interface CustomComparable<T>
{
    public int compare(T a, T b);
}
```

If I try to create an anonymous inner class using Comparable, it's fine...

```
public void someThing()
{
    Comparable<Object> o = new Comparable<Object>()
    {
        public int compareTo(Object o)
        {
            // ...
        }
    };
}
```

With my interface I get the error outlined above. Why? Is `java.lang.Comparable` treated specially?

```
public void someThing()
{
    CustomComparable<Object> o = new CustomComparable<Object>()
    {
        public int compare(Object a, Object b)
        {
            // ...
        }
    };
}
```

I'm using Java 1.6u21 and NetBeans 6.9.1.

Comment: You interface is a comparer, not a comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to use a [`Comparator<T>`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) and not a `Comparable<T>` -- the interface already exists.

Comment: Thanks for that - didn't know there was a `Comparator` interface. ;)

Comment: yes, it's useful for when you have a class with multiple ways of sorting -- just make a Comparator for each sort method.

Comment: Yes, and it couples nicely with anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 2):

This may be trivial, but I hit the same problem in Netbeans 7.0.  The following code gave the same error:

```
       JSlider slider1 = new JSlider(JSlider.HORIZONTAL, -100, 100, 0);
        slider1.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
           public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
               System.out.println("Slider1: " + slider1.getValue());
           }
        });
```

The problem was not fully qualifying the ChangeListener.  I had to import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener.

Answer (score 1):

The following code compiles and runs without error in java 1.6.0_20-b02:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CustomComparable<Object> o = new CustomComparable<Object>()
        {
            public int compare(Object a, Object b)
            {
               System.out.println(a);
               System.out.println(b);
               return 0;
            }
        };
        o.compare("a", "b");
    }

    public interface CustomComparable<T>
    {
        public int compare(T a, T b);
    }
}
```

Are you sure that the code you posted represents a good test case for your problem?

Comment: This is quite puzzling. I restarted NetBeans and now it doesn't show the error. Perhaps some bug somewhere caused it to forget to update its internal source tree. I think it might have failed to recognize that I'd added an `import` for the package my Comparator was in. Good test case, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this in netbeans 6.9.1 as well (under JDK 1.6_22 fwiw). 
I had several classes in package that were showing errors on some lines in netbeans, but they would compile with no errors. Closing/reopening netbeans didn't solve it, neither did rebuildAll. 
What I did to fix it was to go and "touch" every file in the package to mark them dirty, then built the project again and they went away.

Answer (score 0):

java standard library classes are not treated specially by javac.
you hit a bug in javac, congratualations.

Comment: It was just an issue with NetBeans updating its cache. Good to know that, however.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem recently in NetBeans, but the errors haven't been transient.

`comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // do stuff
    }
});`

Note that they will compile correctly when I use Ant, but NetBeans still flags them with: "internal error; cannot instantiate () at  to ()" and the like. The only other thing that I can say about the error is that the anonymous class is inside of a method inside of two other anonymous classes inside of a static initializer.

I'm on 32-bit x86 OS X 10.6.6 with Java 1.6.0_22 and NetBeans 6.9 with all the current updates.